# Eliminate duplicate responses in a nested for loop

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am working on finding a solution for my discord bot, it is written in Py, it's coded to search in game database apis for a specific player name, if found, it sends a message on discord with the server ID, this part works however now I want to add a message if the player is not found after searching all the databases, here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def whereis(ctx, player):  # General stats
    for element in gameIDs["IDs"]:
        url0 = apiLink1 + "/players/?gameId=" + element
        r = requests.get(url0)
        rs = r.json()
        a = rs['teams'][0]['players']
        b = rs['teams'][1]['players']
        c = a + b
        d = rs['serverinfo']['name']
        for element1 in c:
            if element1["name"] == str(player):
                embed = discord.Embed(title=player + " HAS BEEN FOUND",description=d)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                break
            else:
                print("not found")
```

The first for loop is to have every database id checked, the second for loop is to verify every database with the given player, my current solution returns a "not found" for every gameID instance, which I understand why, but I would only like for it to send the message once the gameIDs list has been exhausted. How would I proceed with this?

Thank you all so much in advance.

Comment: This isn't super clean, but can you just test whether `embed` has been populated at the end of the loop, and if not, print your message?

Comment: This is exactly what I have been trying to do, but I haven't found a way to verify if an embed has been populated, I am sure this would work. The other solution worked so I will use that one for now, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just adding a `player_found` bool and print if it is not found?

```
async def whereis(ctx, player):  # General stats
    player_found = False
    for element in gameIDs["IDs"]:
        url0 = apiLink1 + "/players/?gameId=" + element
        r = requests.get(url0)
        rs = r.json()
        a = rs['teams'][0]['players']
        b = rs['teams'][1]['players']
        c = a + b
        d = rs['serverinfo']['name']
        for element1 in c:
            if element1["name"] == str(player):
                player_found = True
                embed = discord.Embed(title=player + " HAS BEEN FOUND",description=d)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                break
    if not player_found:
        print("not found")
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, although I had no idea this could be done. I will definitely learn more about boolean logic now.  Thank you, you are my hero.